# How to unittest functions that relies on External Dependencies such as File Directory and Api Responses

Tags: python, unit-testing

Folks i want to unit test a function which basically downloads a file, but i just don't have any idea of how to do it. This is the code:

```
from requests import get
from helpers.file_helper import get_file_path


def download_file(url, filename):
    r = get(url)
    filepath = get_file_path(filename)
    with open(filepath, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(r.content)
```

I'd like to know how you guys will approach this problem, and if it's possible explain it in simple terms so everybody can understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pytest's [temporary file/directory fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/tmpdir.html) to download the file, read and test the output and be sure everything is clean afterwards. As for the API, you can mock it if you do not want to call it every-time you run the test (either wiht [pytest-mock](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-mock/) or the [mock package](https://mock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) itself

Comment: I'm currently using unittest, so what's the equivalent of temporary file/directory fixtures in unittest

Comment: you can use python's tempfile module (https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) alongside unittest's fixtures (https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#class-and-module-fixtures)